# randomize player color listing in javascript

Tags: jquery, random

I have a chess pairing page at http://verlager.com/super-dev.php. The problem is that I need to randomize the player's colors because I am just listing the players in descending order by rating. The higher rated player always gets the white pieces. Not good.

I think I should take the first two players, and randomize a number. If the random number is > 0.5, then the first player has white, else the second player has white. List them out. Then take the next two players and do the same. Any suggestions?

```
<script>

    // input data

    var toSort = "attaya, james j|blazak, stephen a|larrategui, martin|lionti, michael p|mackenzie, randolph|sassone, richard a|saxby, quinton tyl|trowbridge, james|".split("|");

    // SOLUTION:
    // create a map.
    var nameRatingMap = {};
    members.forEach(function(element) {
        nameRatingMap[element.Name] = element.Rating;
    });

    // use map for sorting
    var sorted = toSort.sort(function(a, b) {
        var ratingA = nameRatingMap[a] || 0;
        var ratingB = nameRatingMap[b] || 0;
        return ratingB - ratingA;
    })


    for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        $temp = sorted[i - 1];

//if (i % 2 !== 0) {random = Math.random();} 
//if (random > 0.5;) {player_1 = sorted[i - 1]; player_2 = sorted[i];}


        if ($temp && $temp.length > 0) {     
            var $full = $temp.split(","); var $nick = $full[0]; 
            $name = $nick.substr( 0, 16);
            $("#I" + i).val($name + ", " + $full[1].substr(0, 1) + ". " + members.find(x => x.Name === $temp).Rating);

        }
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using CSS3

**JS**

```
sorted.forEach((n, x) => {
  let a = n.split(','),
      r;

  if (nameRatingMap[n]) {
    r = nameRatingMap[n];
    $('#I' + x).val(a[0] + '; ' + r);
  }
});
```

**CSS**

```
input:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

input:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oyXWZO

## Using `{n} % 2 === 0`

**JS**

```
sorted.forEach((n, x) => {
  let a = n.split(','),
      r, c;

  if (nameRatingMap[n]) {
    r = nameRatingMap[n];
    c = (x % 2 === 0) ? 'red' : 'blue';
    $('#I' + x).val(a[0] + '; ' + r)
      .css({
        background: c,
        color: '#fff'
      });
  }
});
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKdRzQ